# Where can I find short videos of examples of RL being used?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I would like to add a short ~1-3 minute video to a presentation, to demonstrate how Reinforcement Learning is used to solve problems. I am thinking something like a short gif of an agent playing an Atari game, but for my audience it would probably be better to have something more manufacturing/industry based.

Does anyone know any good sources where I could find some stuff like this?

Comment: Does your presentation need to be stand-alone? Google Slides can embed YouTube videos very simply. I did just that for a presentation on RL recently, and simply used YouTube's search. The advanced version lets you select short clips. DeepMind, OpenAI and others upload clips there.

Comment: @NeilSlater I'm not sure what the format has to be actually -- I was using Overleaf but if my supervisor says it is okay then I can check out Google slides. Thanks!

Comment: Please, have a look at [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/23435/what-are-some-programming-oriented-resources-for-reinforcement-learning), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/18798/what-are-some-online-courses-for-deep-reinforcement-learning), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22010/what-introductory-books-to-reinforcement-learning-do-you-know-and-how-do-they-a) and [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/whats-a-good-resource-for-getting-familiar-with-reinforcement-learning). If any of those answers answer your question, let me know

Comment: @Arpit-Gole no, these look like sources to lectures etc. I'm not looking for lectures/resources for learning, I want a video demonstration e.g. of a robotic hand that was trained by RL.

Answer (score 1):

You can take some ideas from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgvyzIkgxF0) YouTube video .

In addition, you should consider [that](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/) page which is about Deep Reinforcement Learning used in a game (Pong from Pixels) .