# Textbooks (or other sources) on deep reinforcement learning which explain theory along with good examples

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, books

I am looking for a textbook/other sources on deep reinforcement learning which explain theory along with  good examples. I will be happy for suggestions.

Comment: For me was "The Art of Reinforcement Learning" by Michael Hu the best book so far.
On the other side I found the Sutton and Barto Book extremely hard to digest.
By the way, check this link out: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/whats-a-good-resource-for-getting-familiar-with-reinforcement-learning?rq=1

Comment: MARL is not part of this book.

Comment: I will often peruse MIT/Stanford for a class on a subject and check the syllabus for what they’re teaching from.

Comment: @foreverska can you provide any link?

Comment: @DSPinfinity you never mentioned, that you want MARL . In that case I can only suggest the www.neuralnet.ai Academy realized by Phil Tabor. Hi goes into MARL as well.

Comment: @Dave  A lot of the deep RL classes are short on book recommendations other than S&B and some DL book of choice.  But I did find https://www.ji.sjtu.edu.cn/wp-content/uploads/formidable/15/Course-Syllabus-VE693-Fall2021.pdf which says they recommend as reference: "An Introduction to Deep Reinforcement Learning. Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning"

Comment: @Dave Please, write that as an actual answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some online courses for deep reinforcement learning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/18798/what-are-some-online-courses-for-deep-reinforcement-learning), [What introductory books to reinforcement learning do you know, and how do they approach this topic?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/22010/2444) or [What's a good resource for getting familiar with reinforcement learning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/6997/2444). Your question is not an exact duplicate but maybe those questions already have the answer.

Comment: If not, I recommend you edit your post and state that. And then I'd encourage users to actually provide answers instead of writing comments

Answer (score 0):

For me was "The Art of Reinforcement Learning" by Michael Hu the best book so far. On the other side I found the Sutton and Barto Book extremely hard to digest. By the way, check this [link](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/whats-a-good-resource-for-getting-familiar-with-reinforcement-learning?rq=1) out.

In case you need MARL or are interested in it, then I suggest the very well academy course made by Phil Tabor [www.neuralnet.ai](http://www.neuralnet.ai)
It costs some money but it was (for me) definetely worthly